# Recuperar valor selecionado de um select no banco de dados

Tags: php, html

Não consigo recuperar o valor que está gravado do `select`.

Tenho esta recuperação por `input` que está funcionando normalmente.

```html
<td>
   <div class="drop-down-select opcoes ">
      <label for="bairro">Bairro:</label>
      <input type="text" size="50"  class="form-control" id="bairro" name="bairro" value = "<?php echo $bairro;?>" >
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="drop-down-select opcoes ">
      <label for="rua">Rua:</label>        
      <input type="text" size="70"  class="form-control" id="rua" name="rua" value = "<?php echo $rua;?>" >
   </div>         
</td>
```

Mas se possível, queria recuperar estes dados pelo Select, segue o código abaixo...

```html
<td width="160">
   <div class="drop-down-select opcoes ">
      <label for="bairro">Bairro:</label>
      <select name="bairro" id="bairro" required>
         <option value="">Selecione</option>
         <?php foreach ($bairros as $bairro) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $bairro['id'] ?>"><?php echo $bairro['nome'] ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
      </select>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="drop-down-select opcoes ">
      <label for="rua">Rua:</label>
      <select name="rua" id="rua" disabled required>
         <option value="<?php $rua; ?>">Selecione uma Rua</option>
      </select> 
   </div>         
</td>
```

Este é o mesmo select dinâmico que uso para o cadastro.
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Existe algum erro no console/página? O select de bairro me parece correto.

Uma coisa que não entendi no seu código é se o $rua é uma ARRAY de ruas, ou se é só uma opção. Se existir mais de uma rua para ser escolhida, você deve usar um foreach exatamente como voce usou no bairro.

Ajustei uma parte do código HTML, e dei duas opções para pegar o elemento com JavaScript.

[Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/qk5wwyct/) você encontra um exemplo com angular 1, caso esteja usando.

```js
// JS PURO:
var meuElementoHTML = document.getElementById("rua"); // armazena o ELEMENTO HTML com id RUA na variável meuElementoHTML
var value = meuElementoHTML.options[meuElementoHTML.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(meuElementoHTM);
console.log(value);

// J QUERY:
$("#rua :selected").text(); // Texto exibido nesse elemento
$("#rua").val(); // Valor da opção selecionada
```

```html
<td width="160">
   <div class="drop-down-select opcoes ">
      <label for="bairro">Bairro:</label>
      <select name="bairro" id="bairro" required>
         <option value="">Selecione</option>
         <?php foreach ($bairros as $bairro) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $bairro['id'] ?>"><?php echo $bairro['nome'] ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
      </select>
   </div>
</td>
<td>
   <div class="drop-down-select opcoes ">
      <label for="rua">Rua:</label>
      <select name="rua" id="rua" required>
      <option value="">Selecione uma Rua</option>
         <option value="<?php echo $rua; ?>"><?php echo $rua?></option> <!-- TINHA FALTADO O ECHO PRA PRINTAR A VARIAVEL RUA -->
      </select> 
   </div>         
</td>
```

Comment: Ainda não deu certo.

Acrescentei isto...

$("#bairro :selected").text(); ... ... ...

Apareceu o bairro correto, mas não apareceu a rua, tipo, pra aparecer a rua, eu teria que selecionar um outro bairro que não pertencia a atualização da informação. Na opção rua, dizia que o valor estava sem definição.
A $rua é dependente do $bairro, ou seja, pra ver a rua, tem que escolher o bairro (dinâmico).

Comment: Entendi. É algo mais complexo do que eu imaginava, acho que não consigo te ajudar... O que eu posso recomendar, pra tentar ajudar, é que você tem q detectar o evento de mudança daquele elemento (bairro) e chamar uma função que vai fazer a requisição na tua API, retornar os dados em JSON, e aí sim você faz um .append() na div pai (select) criando um novo elemento <option> passando o value e name com o q voce recebeu daquela API...

Sei que te dar o código pronto seria o correto, mas nem eu sei fazer isso, só tenho uma ideia do que pode ser feito. Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.